# How to pass main class as command line arg in gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I need to add second main class to my gradle Spring Boot application and run it depending on command line argument. How to do it? In my `build.gradle` file I have this:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

mainClassName = 'com.example.MyApplication'
```

How to run the application with, for example, `com.example.MySecondApplication` main class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t conditionally choose a main class in your `build.gradle` that depend on command-line args that don’t exist yet. The simplest thing to do would be to have a single main class and branch according to user-provided args. That’s what all command-line apps do.