# is it possible to specify the spring-boot-maven-plugin main class at runtime?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using the spring-boot-maven-plugin to repackage a non spring application. This works fine as long as the main class is known at compile time. But I also have a jar that contains a number of importers, and it should be started using something like:

```
java -cp <jarfile> <mainclass>
```

This won't work, because the main class that needs starting is of course the spring boot launcher. So I need a way to tell the launcher at runtime what main class to start. Something like

```
java -DstartClass=<mainclass> -jar <jarfile>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass main class as command line arg in gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75731020/how-to-pass-main-class-as-command-line-arg-in-gradle). Note that the answer applies to any build tool, not only Gradle.

Comment: No, but it is possible using another spring-boot jar layout.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is supported if you use PropertiesLauncher. To use this launcher, configure repackaging to produce a jar that uses ZIP layout. You can then specify the main class using -Dloader.main=

Credits go to Andy Wilkinson
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/36447